# how to give dynamic table field color as per the value in it

Tags: php, css

I have a dynamic table in that a field `id="complaint_status"` values it can take  `"PENDING"` and `"CLEARED"` only.

Please help to give the field different background color according to these values:

- GREEN for CLEARED
- RED for PENDING

Is there any way to apply conditional CSS?

My codes are below (I could not include all of my code due to limitations):

```
<?php require_once('Connections/my_connection.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<!--[if IE 6]><link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<link href="jquery.ui-1.5.2/themes/ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
#content table tr td {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#wrapper #page #content table {
    color: #000000;
}
#content table {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.link {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.pending{

    background-color:#F00;
    }
    .cleared{

    background-color:#0F0;
    }



</style>


<script src="jquery.ui-1.5.2/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.ui-1.5.2/ui/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Dynamic Selects by Kaosweaver
// Copyright 2007, All rights reserved

</head>
<body>
<?php 
include ('header.php');
?>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page" class="container">
<div id="content">

        <div class="title">

                <h2><a href="#">KNOW YOUR COMPLAINT STATUS</a></h2>
                <span class="byline">search your complaints by any of these category</span> </div>

            <form id="form1" action="" method="post">
            <p>
            <fieldset>
            <table width="648" height="248" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" dir="ltr">
    <tr>
      <td width="275" align="left" class="letter"><strong class="letter">Search Complaints by Date:</strong></td>
      <td width="187" align="left"><strong class="letter">From:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" name="from_date" size="25"  id="jQueryUICalendar1" value=Choose...>      
        <script type="text/javascript">
// BeginWebWidget jQuery_UI_Calendar: jQueryUICalendar1
jQuery("#jQueryUICalendar1").datepicker();

// EndWebWidget jQuery_UI_Calendar: jQueryUICalendar1
        </script></td>
       <td width="182" align="left"><strong class="letter">To:
      </strong><br />
        <input type="text" name="to_date" size="25" id="jQueryUICalendar2" value=Choose...>

        <script type="text/javascript">
// BeginWebWidget jQuery_UI_Calendar: jQueryUICalendar2
jQuery("#jQueryUICalendar2").datepicker();

// EndWebWidget jQuery_UI_Calendar: jQueryUICalendar2
        </script></td>       


    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
      <td align="left" class="letter"><strong>Search Complaints by No:</strong></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="complaint_no" id="complaint_no" size="25">

      </td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" class="letter"><strong>
        <label for="lodged_by">Search Complaints Lodged By:</label>
      </strong></td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="text" name="lodged_by" id="lodged_by" size="25" ></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" class="letter"><strong>
        <label for="comp_item_sl_no">Search CompIaints by tem Sl No:</label>
      </strong></td>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="text" name="comp_item_sl_no" id="comp_item_sl_no" size="25" ></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" class="letter">Search By Section:</td>
      <td align="left"><span class="letter">
        Branch: <br />
          <select name="branch" id="branch" style="width:182px">
          <option>Choose...</option>
          <option value="SASO">SASO</option>
          <option value="SMSO">SMSO</option>
          <option value="AOC">AOC</option>
          <option value="SOA">SOA</option>
          <option value="TCU">TCU</option>
          <option value="REB">REB</option>
          <option value="DCMU">DCMU</option>
          <option value="1 P&amp;S">1 P&amp;S</option>
          <option value="4 LU">4 LU</option>
          <option value="7 ASC">7 ASC</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>
      <td align="left"><span class="letter">
        Section:<br />

            <select name="section" id="section" style="width:182px">
          <option>---------------------------------</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>


    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
      <td colspan="3" class="letter"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </p><input name="button" type="submit"  class="button" align="left" id="button" onclick="MM_validateForm('complaint_no','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Search" />
    </form>
    <p></p>



    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
    <tr bgcolor="#5C94DF" class="">
    <td>COMPLAINT NO</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">ITEM SL NO</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">ITEM NAME</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">INV NO</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">LODGED BY</td>
    <td>COMPLAINT DATE</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">DESCRIPTION</td>
    <td>COMPLAINT STATUS</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">RECTIFIED BY</td>
    <td>RECTIFICATION DATE</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">REMARKS</td>
  </tr>

<?php
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_section);
    if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($rs_section, 0);
    $row_rs_section = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_section);
    }
?> 


<?php
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_sl);
    if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($rs_sl, 0);
    $row_rs_sl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_sl);
    }
?> 

<?php
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_lodged);
    if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($rs_lodged, 0);
    $row_rs_lodged = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_lodged);
    }
?>  


 <?php do { ?> 
    <?php do { ?> 
     <?php do { ?>
        <?php do { ?>
 <tr class="">
   <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="link"><strong><a href="admin_complaints_modify.php?complaint_no=<?php echo $row_rs_datewise['complaint_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['complaint_no']; ?></a><a href="admin_complaints_modify.php?complaint_no=<?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['complaint_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['complaint_no']; ?></a><a href="admin_complaints_modify.php?complaint_no=<?php echo $row_rs_lodged['complaint_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['complaint_no']; ?></a><a href="admin_complaints_modify.php?complaint_no=<?php echo $row_rs_section['complaint_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_section['complaint_no']; ?></a><a href="admin_complaints_modify.php?complaint_no=<?php echo $row_rs_sl['complaint_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_sl['complaint_no']; ?></a></strong></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['comp_item_sl_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['comp_item_sl_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['comp_item_sl_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['comp_item_sl_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['comp_item_sl_no']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['comp_item_name']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['comp_item_name']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['comp_item_name']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['comp_item_name']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['comp_item_name']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['inv_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['inv_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['inv_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['inv_no']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['inv_no']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['lodged_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['lodged_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['lodged_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['lodged_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['lodged_by']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['complaint_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['complaint_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['complaint_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['complaint_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['complaint_date']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['complaint_description']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['complaint_description']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['complaint_description']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['complaint_description']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['complaint_description']; ?></td>



   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['complaint_status']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['complaint_status']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['complaint_status']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['complaint_status']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['complaint_status']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['rectified_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['rectified_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['rectified_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['rectified_by']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['rectified_by']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['rectification_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['rectification_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['rectification_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['rectification_date']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['rectification_date']; ?></td>
   <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $row_rs_datewise['comp_remarks']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_complaint_no['comp_remarks']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_lodged['comp_remarks']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_section['comp_remarks']; ?><?php echo $row_rs_sl['comp_remarks']; ?></td>
 </tr>

 <?php } while ($row_rs_datewise = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_datewise)); ?>
     <?php } while ($row_rs_lodged = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_lodged)); ?>
     <?php } while ($row_rs_sl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_sl)); ?>
     <?php } while ($row_rs_section = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_section)); ?>
</table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its easy for you to use PHP condition for color changes.

Comment: Do you use a templating engine? or basic html/php/css page ?
You just have to make a condition in php : compare the value with "pending" and "cleared" in order to assign the correct css class

Comment: Do you want it to dynamically change without a page reload? If the answer is yes, you will have to use javascript. Otherwise you could just make a PHP condition and add a css class according to that.

Comment: Can you shared the code which you have used here. It will be easy to correct that.

Comment: @user3142260: I have added the answer on the basis of your basic requirements. You can implement it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the sample css and how to use this in your code. Assuming that you are able to connect the Database and executed the query successfully. Also, I assumed that there is only column in the row.

```
<style>
.CLEARED{background-color:green;}
.PENDING {background-color:red;}
</style>

<?php
$query="your query";
$resource=mysql_query($query);

echo '<table>';
while($result=mysql_fetch_object($resource)) {
$val=strtoupper($result->complaint_status);
echo '<tr><td id="complaint_status" class="<?php echo $val;?>">$val</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ursitesion says, you can use on your query something like this:

Include this on your CSS code:

```
.CLEARED{background-color:green;}
.PENDING{background-color:red;}
```

Php code:

```
//EXAMPLE OF QUERY
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cleared='CLEARED';
$pending='PENDING';
$status=$row['status'];

if($status==0)
$status='CLEARED';
else $status='PENDING';
echo "<tr><td id='complaint_status' class='$status'>$val</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

---

Check it, it must work dude. Adjust your query (;